Conversion from string to Date with PM is not valid in VB.Net
I am getting the below error while taking data from MS Access database using VB.Net windows application (Framework 4.8).
 System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "06/23/2016 06:04:39 PM" to type 'Date' is not valid.'

Below is the code that I am using.
   menu.SubItems.Add(CDate(dr("Field1").ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt"))

How to solve this ?

The date string quoted in the exception has seconds, your format does not.

I suspect you meant CDate(dr("Field1")).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt") - notice the different placement of the parentheses.

...although ideally dr("Field1") would have already been of type DateTime, so no need for the CDate.

@AndrewMorton, you'd still need the CDate anyway because indexing a DataRow always returns an Object reference. You could use the Field extension method to avoid the need for a cast.

@jmcilhinney I suppose "dr" could stand for "DataReader" rather than "DataRow". So dr.GetDateTime(dr.GetOrdinal("Field1")).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt") could be used, as if that makes any real difference. Too late now anyway.

Why not store dates as dates in the DB?

Try using ParseExact:
Dim textDate As String =  "06/23/2016 06:04:39 PM"
Dim thisDate As DateTime

Dim format As String
Dim provider As System.Globalization.CultureInfo

format = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"
provider = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")

thisDate = DateTime.ParseExact(textDate, format, provider)
Console.WriteLine(thisDate.ToString(format, provider))

' Output:
' 06/23/2016 06:04:39 PM


I don't understand why this is an answer to your question because, based on what you posted, you're trying to convert a Date to a String, not the other way around. If you get a Date from the database and you want to convert that to a String to add to your menu then this is not helping you do that. The issue, as was mentioned in the comments, is just that your parentheses are in the wrong place. If that's not what you're trying to do, why haven't you explained what you're actually trying to do in the question?

@jmcilhinney: I assumed the Field1 to hold text, not DateTime since the exception mentiones "06/23/2016 06:04:39 PM", and a test showed me that CDate, picky as it is, wouldn't convert that value.

I can see why you might think that but I don't think it's possible. CDate is being passed the result of the ToString call, not the value of the DataRow field. If that field actually contained text then that ToString call would be interpreted quite differently and you'd get an exception stating that the string "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt" could not be converted to an Integer.

This really seems like an overblown answer and not really what was asked for. It is more likely that the datatype being received is a date, however the datareader is returning it as object. Closing the parentheses before .ToString(...) is probably enough to answer this question. CDate(dr("Field1")).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt")

When parsing your values from your database, you need to cast them to their appropriate type. Assuming Field1 returns a sql datetime object or something of that nature, you need to cast it to a Date before you call ToString against it. The snippet below breaks apart what you are doing to show the steps in their appropriate order and then provides you a full line of code based on your OP.
'You have the object you read from the db. Its type is generic object.
dim someObject = dr("Field1")

'Now we cast the object to a date
dim someDate as Date = CDate(someObject)

'Now we can tostring it for formatting/display purposes
dim dateString = someDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt")

'Finally, add it to your menu collection
menu.SubItems.Add(dateString)


'All together now...
menu.SubItems.Add(CDate(dr("Field1")).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt"))


And why is someObject not being declared as DateTime? Any data column of datetime will return a strong typed value of DateTime, and hence no need to use Cdate on a object that is already datetime.  So, a datarow column of type DateTime will in fact ALREADY return a strong typed var type of DateTime. It's possible that the column in question is not already a datetime, and is maybe a text column.  However, we don't know that as of yet, and if this was a text column, then DateTime.Parse should be used.

Your experience my be different than mine, however I am used to an exception being throw when using toString against a generic object return type unless I cast before hand. SomeObject was simply returned to a generic inferred type the same as would be returned by the property accessor used to retrieve the column value from data reader.

Not a huge deal, but the ado.net datarow object will return the column as strong typed  object already (no requirement to cast). So, just trying to be 100%, if not 200% clear here! The object will have a type defined for you. So, if the data column is of type datetime, then the object type returned in this case is System.DateTime. All I'm saying is that the data column is NOT of type "just" object, and is NOT of type variant, but is a strong .net typed  valid object type. The type returned thus does not require casting.  So, yes, you can with confidence use .ToString() with a format.

So, to be fair? Yes, you still have to wrap a type around that column returned. So, cDate(dr(0)("columnName).ToString("yyyy MM")
